# Can you use a Django form multiple times in one view?

Tags: django, forms

I have a Django view that uses one form multiple times.  The form is just a boolean field form that is supposed to initialize to *True* but then the user can decide to uncheck the boxes or not.

The problem I'm having is that the all of the fields evaluate to *True* no matter what the user leaves checked.  Is this a problem with using the same form multiple times, or did I mess something else up?

The form looks like this:

```
class DataTypeForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    section_label = kwargs.pop('section_label')
    initial_value = kwargs.pop('initial_value')

    super(DataTypeForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['dataType'].label=mark_safe(section_label)
    self.fields['dataType'].initial=initial_value
    self.fields['dataType'].required=False

dataType = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

This is the view:

```
def Manual_Request(request):

  form_dict = {}
  arg_dict = {}
  message = message = {'last_url':'Nominal_Request'}

  if request.method == 'POST':
    logger.info("Query submitted, beginning query results render for:")

    form_NOM = DataTypeForm(request.POST or None,section_label="ENG_NOM",initial_value=True)
    form_DDM = DataTypeForm(request.POST or None,section_label="SCI_DDM",initial_value=True)
    form_RAW = DataTypeForm(request.POST or None,section_label="SCI_RAW",initial_value=False)

    if form_NOM.is_valid():
        NOM = form_NOM.cleaned_data['dataType']

        arg_dict.update({'ENG_NOM':str(NOM)})
        logger.info("ENG_NOM: {val}".format(val=NOM))

    if form_DDM.is_valid():
        DDM = form_DDM.cleaned_data['dataType']

        arg_dict.update({'SCI_DDM':str(DDM)})
        logger.info("SCI_DDM: {val}".format(val=DDM))

    if form_RAW.is_valid():
        RAW = form_RAW.cleaned_data['dataType']

        arg_dict.update({'SCI_RAW':str(RAW)})
        logger.info("SCI_RAW: {val}".format(val=RAW))

    return Request_Results(request,args_dict)

  else:
    logger.info("Rendering query page")

    form_NOM = DataTypeForm(section_label="ENG_NOM",initial_value=True)
    form_DDM = DataTypeForm(section_label="SCI_DDM",initial_value=True)
    form_RAW = DataTypeForm(section_label="SCI_RAW",initial_value=True)
    form_dict.update({'form_NOM':...etc})

  return render(request,'InterfaceApp/COMMRequest_Manual.html',form_dict)
```

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't run your code, but my best guess is that yes, it's a problem with using the same form multiple times in the same view. The reason? All of your `<input type="checkbox" name="..." ... />` tags will have the same name, `'dataType'`. The user's browser knows nothing of your back-end, and will just send, for example, `dataType=on&dataType=on` as POST data for the three fields if two are checked and one is not.

Seeing the problem here? How is django supposed to know which of those `dataType` fields are for your NOM, DDM, or RAW forms? It can't know.

You should be able to solve this using [form prefixes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms). In short, there's a kwarg that you can pass to a form's `__init__()` that will cause a prefix to be added to all of the form items in the rendered HTML. So, for example:

```py
form_NOM = DataTypeForm(request.POST or None, section_label="ENG_NOM", 
                        initial_value=True, prefix="NOM")
form_DDM = DataTypeForm(request.POST or None, section_label="SCI_DDM",
                        initial_value=True, prefix="DDM")
form_RAW = DataTypeForm(request.POST or None, section_label="SCI_RAW", 
                        initial_value=False, prefix="RAW")
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what Django formsets are for. They allows you to create a set of the same type of form. It handles prefixes, and adds a management form so that Django doesn't get confused as to what data comes from what form.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/